# JSONObject to JSONArray with days as keys

Tags: android, key, arrays

I have the following sample json:

```
{\"2013-05-30\":{\"available\":\"1\",\"bind\":0,\"info\":\"\",\"notes\":\"\",\"price\":\"\",\"promo\":\"\",\"status\":\"available\"},
\"2013-05-31\":{\"available\":\"1\",\"bind\":0,\"info\":\"\",\"notes\":\"\",\"price\":\"\",\"promo\":\"\",\"status\":\"available\"},
\"2013-06-01\":{\"available\":\"1\",\"bind\":0,\"info\":\"\",\"notes\":\"\",\"price\":\"\",\"promo\":\"\",\"status\":\"available\"}}
```

I read this into a String and then parse it into a JSONObject, but I need it to be in a JSONArray.
I have tried adding programmatically "[" at the beginning of the string and "]" at the end of it, before I convert it into a JSONArray, and, although it recognizes it as an Array, it still sees it as a single object (I only seem to have JSONArray(0)).

This is how I try to parse the jsonData as an Array:

```
try{
jArray = new JSONArray(resultString);
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.i("log_4","Available: "+json_data.getString("available")+
        ", Bind: "+json_data.getString("bind")+
        ", Info: "+json_data.getString("info") +
        ", Notes: "+json_data.getString("notes") +
        ", Price: "+json_data.getString("price") +
        ", Promo: "+json_data.getString("promo") +
        ", Status: "+json_data.getString("status")
        );
    }
}catch(JSONException e){
Log.e("log_5", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
```

and here is the version in which I don't add [ and ], therefore parsing it as a JSONObject.

```
try {
    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resString);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("log_3", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
```

How can I separate each day (e.g."2013-05-30") into a different object, with each object having as key the value of the day?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a `[` at the begining and a `]` at the end, try replacing the first instance of `{` with `[` and the last instance of `}` with `]` and then making a JSONArray out of it.

Comment: I tried that too, but then I would have the following error: `org.JSONException: Unterminated Array at character 14 of` String, which would be the first `:`.

Comment: Sorry that was a bad idea, that would just create an JSON map which the android api does not support. You can use `JSONObject.keys()` to get an `Iterator` to the keys. Then use that to iterate all the keys and fetch the corresponding JSON Object. This doesn't give you a JSONArray but you can still iterate the JSONObject like an array.

Comment: You can also try using `JSONObject.getNames(JSONObject)` this returns a `String[]` of variable names in the `JSONObject` you can then use these to fetch the JSONObjects.

Comment: Problem is I don't know the values of days. This is a sample JSON, but normally I cannot know the value.

Comment: Okay @Elena use `JSONObject.getNames(JSONObject)` this should give you a `String[]` with the dates.

Comment: It worked with some adjustments to the String. Another mention would be that the correct form is `JSONObject.names()`. Thanks for helping me out!